# Como Retornar resultados com inteiros e nulos?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, null

Estou tentando montar uma Query porem não estão tendo sucesso, no meu banco de dado tenho 28 informações com o código 32, e 62 informações com o código 23, porém existem informações com o código nulo, e eu queria trazer todas elas juntas, o problema é que quando tento buscar o resultado jogando os códigos na Tag WHERE a consulta vem vazia.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo IN (23, 32, NULL);
```

tentei assim também:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo IN (23, 32) AND campo IS NULL;
```

Alguém teria uma solução ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo IN (23, 32) OR campo IS NULL`, já tentou?

Comment: Sim, nesse caso trouxe só os nulos e não trouxe os campos com 23 e 32 juntos... Preciso que traga os nulos e os com codigo 23 e 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foi quase colega, tenta isso:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo IN (23, 32) OR campo IS NULL;
```

Comment: Trouxe só os nulos, preciso que retorne os nulos e com codigo 23 e 32.

Comment: SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo IN (23, 32) AND campo IS NULL;

Comment: Tentei de novo e deu certo, Valeu Victo Zanella, valeu Marconi a query deu certo, ficou da seguinte forma:  SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo IN (23, 32) OR campo IS NULL;

Comment: @LucasLima, mas qual foi a diferença ?

Comment: Tinha digitado errado esqueci do IS tinha colocado só NULL, ai verifiquei vi que estava errado comparando com o seu, e deu certo.

Comment: iuehiuehiue, beleza